# Access the history of responses of a useQuery hook that uses polling

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-toolkit, polling, rtk-query

In my app, I need to display the historic state of a server, similar to following image:

[image]

The endpoint I use is a normal GET fetch. So I need polling to retrieve the data periodically:

```
  const { data, isFetching, error } = useGetServerStateDataQuery(id, {
    pollingInterval: 3000,
  })
  console.log(data) // data only contains LAST response :(
```

The problem is that `data` only contains **last response**, and **I need the historic of all responses** to be able to draw the progress. Is there any built-in `redux-toolkit` solution to access the history of responses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple approach:

### Using extra reducers

You can link a [`timestamp` in the `meta`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#adding-meta-information-to-queries)

Then plug the result of your endpoint into an [extra reducer](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/examples#using-extrareducers) to keep track of this history of results

```js
const weatherSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'weather',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
     history: {}
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(api.endpoints.getServerStateDataQuery.fullfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.history[action.meta.timestamp] = action.payload
    })
  },
})
```

### Using entity adapters

You can store each temperature info into an entity object with an [entity adapter](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#createentityadapter)

```js
const weatherInfoAdapter = createEntityAdapter<Book>({
  selectId: (info) => info.id,
  sortComparer: (a, b) => a.timestamp.localeCompare(b.timestamp),
})

const weatherSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'weather',
  initialState: weatherInfoAdapter.getInitialState(),
  reducers: {
     history: {}
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
     builder.addCase(api.endpoints.getServerStateDataQuery.fullfilled, (state, action) => {
      weatherInfoAdapter.addOne(state, action.payload)
    })
  },
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Interesting approach. However my server data depends on a given ID, is there any way to access it in `extraReducers`?

Comment: Yes if you pass this id in the response, then you have it on the payload

Comment: If you have the ID you can use the second approach with the entity adapter, because you want to store multiple entities, they all have a different time, then with this time and all of theses entity you create a graph

Comment: the originalArgs should also be somewhere in `action.meta` - `console.log` that out and look around.